# Class not found after "require_once"

Tags: php, class, require-once

I get the following error:

```
`Fatal error: Class 'DummyClass' not found in...`
```

---

```
<?php

 require_once("3rdparty/simplesaml/lib/_autoload.php");

 class login extends DummyClass { (this is the line the error refers to)

 [...]

 }

?>
```

If I comment out the `require_once` it works perfectly fine.

DummyClass is defined externally and can be found in the prepend-file. (I don't think it matters for this problem as it works as expected if I comment out `require_once`)

The path to the file should also be correct as it gives me a "Failed opening required..." Error if I change the path.

I also tried switching between PHP 5.6 and 7 - no difference.

So, I would like to ask you for help. Do you have any hints / ideas, why I might get that error?

Comment: This sounds like it could be an issue of namespacing. What namespace is `DummyClass` defined in and what namespace is your script in now? If `DummyClass` is in the default namespace, does `extends \DummyClass` help?

Comment: Another thing to ask - were you using an autoload function already before including the simplesaml autoload?

Comment: Yes, the prepend-file contains a `function __autoload($classname){`.
The `\DummyClass` did not help. Although, I am just trying to figure out the namespaces. As it's a whole framework behind "DummyClass", it's not as easy to just echo something.

Comment: \_\_NAMESPACE__ does not contain anything, neither with or without the problematic line.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The old framework was using the old `__autoload` function, which is deprecated.
SimpleSAMLPHP used the new function. Those autoload-combinations cause one of them to override the other.

Solution:

Switch from `__autoload` to `spl_autoload_register`.

Similar Question: [Override vendor autoload composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913441/override-vendor-autoload-composer)